# Is it possible to style a mouseover on an image map using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an image on a web page that also requires links. I am using an image map to create the links and I am wondering if there is a way to style the area shape on mouseover for a minor touch of interactivity. Is this possible?

I tried this without success:

html

```
<img src="{main_photo}" alt="locations map"  usemap="#location-map" />
<map name="location-map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="208,230,290,245" href="{site_url}locations/grand_bay_al" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="307,214,364,226" href="{site_url}locations/mobile_al" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="317,276,375,290" href="{site_url}locations/loxley_al" />
</map>
```

css

```
area { border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I already did that once, but I had to use JavaScript, my areas were all images that got highlighted, was a pain to crop all those images, but it was working. I don't think there is any way to do that in CSS. Unless `map area:hover { border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; }` works...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### CSS Only:

Thinking about it on my way to the supermarket, you could of course also skip the entire image map idea, and make use of `:hover` on the elements on top of the image (changed the divs to a-blocks). Which makes things hell of a lot simpler, no jQuery needed...

Short explanation:

- Image is in the bottom
- 2 x a with display:block and absolute positioning + opacity:0
- Set opacity to 0.2 on hover

## Example:

```css
.area {
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    height:475px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
}
#area2 {
    left:320px;
}
#area1:hover, #area2:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<a id="area1" class="area" href="#"></a>
<a id="area2" class="area" href="#"></a>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Saimiri_sciureus-1_Luc_Viatour.jpg/640px-Saimiri_sciureus-1_Luc_Viatour.jpg" width="640" height="475" />
```

## Original Answer using jQuery

I just created something similar with jQuery, I don't think it can be done with CSS only.

**Short explanation:**

- Image is in the bottom
- Divs with rollover (image or color) with absolute positioning + display:none
- Transparent gif with the actual `#map` is on top (absolute position) (to prevent call to `mouseout` when the rollovers appear)
- jQuery is used to show/hide the divs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#location-map')) {
    $('#location-map area').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $('#overlay' + id).show();

      });

      $(this).mouseout(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#overlay' + id).hide();
      });

    });
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

#emptygif {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
}

#overlayr1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

#overlayr2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  top: 160px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.tfo.be/jobs/axa/premiumplus/img/empty.gif" width="300" height="350" border="0" usemap="#location-map" id="emptygif" />
<div id="overlayr1">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="overlayr2">&nbsp;</div>
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_nP6ESfPiKIw/SlOGugKqaoI/AAAAAAAAACs/6jnPl85TYDg/s1600-R/monkey300.jpg" width="300" height="350" border="0" />
<map name="location-map" id="location-map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,300,160" href="#" id="r1" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,161,300,350" href="#" id="r2"/>
</map>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: fixing your fiddle would be awesome!

Comment: I liked the CSS-Only solution personally.

In my case I also moved the width parameter from .area class into the #area2 block and made additional #areaX blocks (#area1, #area3, #area4, etc) with different width values so I could have an image with multiple hover areas of different widths (example being an image of a row-of-rooms map, each room having different widths, but all the same height.

Answer (score 17):

With pseudo elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-map-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/FibonacciBlocks.png" alt="" usemap="#image-map" />
    <div class="map-selector"></div>
</div>

<map name="image-map" id="image-map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="54,36,66,49" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="72,38,83,48" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="56,4,80,28" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="7,7,45,46" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="10,59,76,125" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="93,9,199,122" />
</map>
```

some CSS:

```
.image-map-container {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.image-map-container img {
    display:block;
}
.image-map-container .map-selector {
    left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    color:#546E7A00;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-property: top, left, right, bottom, color;
}
.image-map-container .map-selector.hover {
    color:#546E7A80;
}

.map-selector:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit;right: inherit;bottom: inherit;left: inherit;
    background: currentColor;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-property: top, left, right, bottom, background;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#image-map area').hover(
    function () { 
        var coords = $(this).attr('coords').split(','),
            width = $('.image-map-container').width(),
            height = $('.image-map-container').height();
        $('.image-map-container .map-selector').addClass('hover').css({
            'left': coords[0]+'px',
            'top': coords[1] + 'px',
            'right': width - coords[2],
            'bottom': height - coords[3]
        })
    },
    function () { 
        $('.image-map-container .map-selector').removeClass('hover').attr('style','');
    }
)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79ebt32x/1/

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible just using CSS (not cross browser at least) but the jQuery plugin ImageMapster will do what you're after. You can outline, colour in or use an alternative image for hover/active states on an image map.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

Comment: it is possible, see Jason answer below

Comment: That's pretty cunning.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one that is pure css that uses the `+` next sibling selector, `:hover`, and `pointer-events`.  It doesn't use an imagemap, technically, but the `rect` concept totally carries over:

```css
.hotspot {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.hotspot + * {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
.hotspot:hover + * {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.wash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; height: 188px; width: 300px;">
    <img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg">
        
    <div class="hotspot" style="top: 50px; left: 50px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="wash"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">A</div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="hotspot" style="top: 100px; left: 120px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="wash"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of using the sibling connector for this. It's a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by just changing the html. Here's an example:

```
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <map name="navigatemap">
    <area shape="rect"  
          coords="166,4,319,41" 
          href="WII.htm"  
          onMouseOut="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome).png'" 
          onMouseOver="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome,MouseOverWII).png'" 
    />
    <area shape="rect"
          coords="330,4,483,41" 
          href="OT.htm"  
          onMouseOut="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome).png'" 
          onMouseOver="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome,MouseOverOT).png'" 
    />

    <area shape="rect" 
          coords="491,3,645,41" 
          href="OP.htm"  
          onMouseOut="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome).png'" 
          onMouseOver="navbar.src='Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome,MouseOverOP).png'" 
   />
  </map> 

  <img src="Assets/NavigationBar(OnHome).png" 
     name="navbar" 
     usemap="#navigatemap" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers (chrome, edge) Area::hover::after css is supported.

Something like this should work:

```
<style>
   #a1::hover::after {
     position:absolute;
     display:block;
     content: ' ';
     border: 2px solid red;
     top: 10px;
     left: 10px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
   }
</style>
<map name="image-map" id="image-map">
  <area id="a1" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="10,10,20,20"> 
</map>
<img src="foo.png" usemap="#image-map" />
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6z2w9trL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to jump on this question late in the game but I have an answer for irregular (non-rectangular) shapes. I solved it using SVGs to generate masks of where I want to have the event attached.

The idea is to attach events to inlined SVGs, super cheap and even user friendly because there are plenty of programs for generating SVGs. The SVG can have a layer of the image as a background.

http://jcrogel.com/code/2015/03/18/mapping-images-using-javascript-events/

Comment: Link returns 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Canvas

in HTML, simply add a canva

```
<canvas id="locations" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser can't read canvas</canvas>
```

And in Javascript (only an example, that will draw a rectangle on the picture)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("locations");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = '{main_photo}';
img.onload = function() {    // after the pic is loaded
    ctx.drawImage(this,0,0); // add the picture
    ctx.beginPath();         // start the rectangle
    ctx.moveTo(50,50);
    ctx.lineTo(200,50);
    ctx.lineTo(200,200);
    ctx.lineTo(50,200);
    ctx.lineTo(50,50);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "sienna"; // set color
    ctx.stroke();               // apply color
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    // ctx.closePath();
};
```