# Image hover when over area <map>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get different images to load when hovering over the different image map zones. Is this even possible with htlm/css or java? If so how?

Thanks

Here's my code so far:

```
<img id="navbar" src="img/index-navbar.png" usemap="#navmap"/>
        <map name="navmap">
            <area id="index-hover" shape="poly" coords="0,113,125,77,126,129,0,168,0,113" href="index.html" alt="" title="" />
            <area id="selfstudy-hover" shape="poly" coords="127,77,281,66,271,118,128,129,127,77" href="selfstudy.html" alt="" title="" />
            <area id="exhibits-hover" shape="poly" coords="284,66,432,73,433,123,274,118,284,66" href="exhibits.html" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="434,73,602,87,593,138,435,123,434,73" href="committees.html" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="605,88,787,98,788,150,597,139,605,88" href="newsletters.html" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="789,98,852,95,959,59,959,114,887,143,789,151,789,98" href="selfstudy-design.html" alt="" title="" />
        </map>
```

Comment: I think you mean "Javascript".  Java != Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a mouseover on an image map using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

hopefully this helps, i did something like this years ago on specialolympics.org

your html

```
    <div class="world_map_container">
<img src="http://www.specialolympics.org/RegionsImages/map/transparent.gif" usemap="#the_world_map" id="transparent_map">
<img src="http://www.specialolympics.org/RegionsImages/map/world_map.png"><map name="the_world_map" id="the_world_map">
<area shape="poly" coords="69,86,83,71,83,51,70,30,52,16,18,36,5,53,23,74,53,83," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/north-america/_Region-Front/North-America.aspx" id="area_northamerica">
<area shape="poly" coords="63,94,77,89,99,99,87,138,72,138,63,108," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/latin-america/_Region-Front/Latin-America.aspx" id="area_southamerica">
<area shape="poly" coords="120,70,178,63,220,60,262,57,232,28,191,29,147,32,122,62," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/europe-eurasia/_Region-Front/Europe-Eurasia.aspx" id="area_eurasia">
<area shape="poly" coords="115,94,134,92,146,90,167,99,160,122,131,125,120,106," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/africa/_Region-Front/Africa.aspx" id="area_africa">
<area shape="poly" coords="112,84,137,87,152,87,152,80,139,74,120,79," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/middle-east-north-africa/_Region-Front/Middle-East-North-Africa.aspx" id="area_middleeast">
<area shape="poly" coords="209,68,202,71,190,73,186,81,195,85,206,88,216,84,216,75," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/east-asia/_Region-Section-Front/East-Asia.aspx" id="area_eastasia">
<area shape="poly" coords="192,96,218,91,248,100,259,132,218,133,199,120,197,110," href="http://www.specialolympics.org/Regions/asia-pacific/_Region-Front/Asia-Pacific.aspx" id="area_asiapacific">
</map>
<ul>
<li id="northamerica" style=""><a href="#">north america</a></li>
<li id="southamerica"><a href="#">south america</a></li><li id="eurasia"><a href="#">eurasia</a></li>
<li id="africa"><a href="#">Africa</a></li><li id="middleeast"><a href="#">Middle East</a></li>
<li id="eastasia"><a href="#">East Asia</a></li><li id="asiapacific"><a href="#">Asia Pacific</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

your css

```
 div.world_map_container #transparent_map {
   border: medium none;
  height: 140px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 270px;
 z-index: 30;
}

 ul li {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   z-index: 20;
 }


 #northamerica {
   background: url("/RegionsImages/map/north_america.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0      transparent;
   height: 140px;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 270px;
 }

  #southamerica {
  background: url("/RegionsImages/map/south_america.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
   height: 140px;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 270px;
 }
```

your js

```
      $('.world_map_container area').each(function () {
    // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
        var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');
        $('#' + country_id).css('display', 'block');
    });

    // Assigning an action to the mouseout event
    $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
        var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');
        $('#' + country_id).css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```

you can see on this site now on the right rail http://specialolympics.org/

essentially you place a transparent image over the load image and you switch out map area on the hover and replace with each background area.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this yeeeeeaaaaaarrrrssss ago using CSS and JS. [View and deconstruct the code here.](http://www.mackie.com/products/hrmk2series/cutaway/diagram.html)

You could probably do it with pure CSS these days as there's unified browser support for it. I would do absolutely positioned divs over a background and then use `a {display: none;} a:hover {display: block;}` to make your images show up. Image maps are soooo 20th century ;)

...unless of course you want them to do things onClick, which would still require JavaScript.