# Javascript area image map hover effect with color code #000

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, area

Today I produced my first hotspot image Map with fireworks and I exported as HTML data. My HTML data has href tags, it is good but I like to put a hover effect on the href tags.

Here is my Map: http://davis-design.de/europa/Europa.htm

I don't have any idea how to implement the hover effect in JavaScript. So i will to use a Color Code hover effect not a image hover effect.

Comment: `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` are the javascript hover events

Comment: Hey, can you give me a example Code.

Comment: `<a href="path/to/whatever" onmouseover="triggerFunctionOn()" onmouseout="triggerFunctionOff()">Link Name</a>` this will call those functions mouse on/off. What the function does is up to you

Comment: @PRPGFerret OMG read question ............ what are you talking about???

Comment: see this link... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css