# How to map an image in html by drawing small rectangles or squares on it?

Tags: css, html

I have a image of map of a country.I want to click on a state and go to next page .How can i make some small rectangles or squares or circles on each state so that when i click them it links to respective page using html or css ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a feature in HTML called [Image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), which you can use like this:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Website map" usemap="#mapname" />
<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="9,372,66,397" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" alt="Wikipedia" title="Wikipedia" >
</map>
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css) if you want to add further style and functionality.

Comment: This map attribute and area attribute wil map the whole state . I want to create small rectangles on the states and click on it to link to other page.

Comment: You use multiple areas and use the coords to declare your rectangles, and you can also use circles (`shape="circle"`). Updated the answer with more reference.