# Png treated as rectangle - can I ignore transparent areas?

Tags: html

I mainly use canvas where this isn't an issue but this is for a HTML project.

I have a png that is going to be a button and I want the transparent area of the png not to be picked up on mouse events. HTML deals with elements as rectangles, so is this even possible?

Comment: You can use `border-radius` if your PNG is rounded rect. But not if it is polygonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Image Map to define the clickable area of the image.

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/images/imagemaps.html

Here is the gist of the link:

1. Create the map code using a tool like https://www.image-maps.com/
2. Use the `ismap` and `usemap` attributes on your `img` tag:

   ```
   <img src="media/image1.jpg" ismap="ismap" usemap="#metroid">
   ```

   `metroid` is the name of the map as specified in the `map` tag.

Please note that this approach creates clickable areas that act as a link. From your question, I assume that this is what you want as you were asking about a button.

If you need to react to more mouse events, you can use the approach outlined in [Is it possible to style a mouseover on an image map using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css)