# css on ImageMap hotspot

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have this code which applies a hotspot to an image.

```
<asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMapDemo" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCCCC" HotSpotMode="PostBack" ImageUrl="~/Images/Grd_Red.png" OnClick="ImageMapDemo_Click">
<asp:CircleHotSpot AlternateText="reader1" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="7230209932" Radius="20" X="143" Y="309" />
<asp:CircleHotSpot AlternateText="reader2" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="72309930" Radius="20" X="729" Y="171" />
</asp:ImageMap>
```

Hoovering over this produces a change in the cursor but I'd like to see a larger circle appear, I guess this should be achievable using css but I cannot figure out how to achieve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming this is outputing `area` tags...I don't think you can style those.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css