# I cant make multiple hoverable points on an image

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have a picture of my friends and would like to make something pop up on when I hover over their faces. I am really new to this, so its probably an easy solution, but I can't find one that fits my need.

I have managed to make a map solution that correctly defines an area around their faces and make that a link. The problem is that I can't make that link show anything on hover, just click.

```
<img src="http://104.45.93.236/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/20150621_195100.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="1600" height="900">
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="557,252,632,344" alt="xyz" href="http://104.45.93.236/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/stock2.jpg">
</map>
```

It behaves as expected.

Comment: can you post working code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a mouseover on an image map using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css)